# Increment number php every next number

Tags: php, for-loop, numbers

everything good ? I'm having a problem where I'm a beginner in php and would need help.

the user must enter an initial number, for example: 1

```
<input type="number" name"number" id="number">
```

where he then informs the quantity: 30

```
<input type="number" name"qtd" id="qtd">
```

in case I would like to make a loop in which every 10 repetitions are incremented a new number.

the result of the above example would be:

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3,3

its possible ?

here look my code that i was trying , but i couldn't find a logical way .

```
<?php


//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);


//echo $_POST['sequencial'];


for ($i = 1;  $i <= 100; $i++){
  echo $i. "<br>";
}


?>
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: i was trying for , but this only repeat the number with increment

Comment: You are expected to show your code which you are using. People aren't gonna write the whole thing for you. But they can help you with your broken code.

Comment: how? share the code please.

Comment: `$l = 30; for($v=$i=0; $i<$l; ++$i) { if($i % 10 == 0) { ++$v; } echo $v.','; }` ... if you need more sophistication than that (like f.e. no trailing comma after the last value), then you need to figure that out yourself :-P

Comment: Or, alternative that substitutes modulo for rounding up, and doesn’t need an additional variable for the output value: `for($i=0; $i<$l; ++$i) { echo ceil(($i+1)/10).','; }`

Comment: Thanks 04FS , this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it that way. It works very nice.

```
$str =array();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<10;$j++){
        $str[]=$i;
    }
    $j=0;
}
echo implode($str,',');
```

Comment: This is fixed outputting 100 numbers, in groups of 10 that increment.  So given a quantity of 27 and a starter number of 3, how would this work?

Comment: You can try, only you need to change "i" and "j" counters.